# Why does a column with datatype number(3,2) not accept 22.3 as a value in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a table whose datatype is number(3,2).
I try to insert 22.3 into this column and it gives me an error stating that value larger than specified precision.
My point is that 22.3 has a precision of 3. Then why doesn't it accept this as a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313):

> Optionally, you can also specify a precision (total number of digits) and scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point)

So `NUMBER(3,2)` allows a total of 3 digits, 2 of which are to the right of the decimal point, leaving only one to the left of it. In other words, the largest number that could fit into this column is 9.99.